# How to transform between two layout forms of matrix calculus?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to derive a very simple matrix derivative:

> Take the derivative of $\operatorname{Tr}(A' X)$ with respect to $X$.

However, I got two different answers by following different methods.

**First Method:** vec routine:  $\operatorname{Tr}(A' X) = vec(A)' vec(X)$,  so that $d(\operatorname{Tr}(A'X)) = vec(A)' dvec(X)$, and therefore the derivative is $vec(A)'$.

**Second Method:** element-wise :

$$\frac{\partial \operatorname{Tr}(A^{T}X)}{\partial Xij}%
=\operatorname{Tr}(A^{T}E_{ij})=\operatorname{Tr}(e_{j}^{T}A^{T}e_{i})=A_{ij}$$

And therefore the derivative is $A$.

The first method is following the idea by Steven W. Nydick in this [material](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tc.umn.edu%2F~nydic001%2Fdocs%2Funpubs%2FMagnus_Matrix_Differentials_Presentation.pdf&ei=wuJVUaA3wZnRAemggegD&usg=AFQjCNEtn_iSnPDXjO5V_Uw-9T2IO9oTew&sig2=wd7zE9lgAg1Z_Lx6Eq9smA&bvm=bv.44442042,d.dmQ).

And the Second one is introduced in 'Kronecker product and its application'.

Why these two methods give me different answers? Which one is correct?

ps: I guess I am little bit confused by how the first method is transforming the matrix derivative to vector derivative. Steven's material says that the matrix derivative of $f(X)$ w.r.t $X$ is equal to the derivative of $vec(f(X))$ w.r.t $vec(X)$.

Thanks.

P.s. Thanks to the help of user1551, I see that it is a layout transform issue. But I could not see how the transform is between $d(f(X))/d(X)$ and $d(vec(f(X))/d(vec(X))$,  if $f$ returns a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. They only differ in the layout of the derivative. In the first method, you group the partial derivatives into a vector; in the second one, you group them into a matrix. When people do usual multivariate calculus, they tend to use the first form; when they do matrix calculus, they tend to adopt the second form.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But how can I transform between the two layout?  Since the relation is kind of obvious but still not obvious enough to write down using permutation matrix I guess..especially when it comes to take matrix derivative w.r.t matrix

Comment: @SoManyProblems Do you know what [$\operatorname{vec}(A)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) means? You don't use a permutation matrix and matrix-vector multiplication to get $\operatorname{vec}(A)$ from $A$. Instead, you stack first column of $A$ on top of the second column, the second one on top of the third one and so on.

Comment: yes I understand that. and I of course I know how to transform between vec(X) and X, but you see it is more complicated here.  I can't figure out how d(f(X))/dX  and  d(vec(f(X)))/d(vec(X)) can be transformed back and forth easily. I understand it is just a layout issue, but I could not work it out...

Answer (score 1):

That's correct.  The presentation basically defines the derivative of a function of a matrix w.r.t. a matrix as df(X)/dvec(X)^T, and if you take the derivative of a scalar w.r.t. a transposed vector, you get a transposed vector as the result.

The reason that the presentation (and corresponding book) does this (and why it's done in matrix algebra in general) is so that the derivative of a matrix w.r.t. a matrix is able to be organized:

da/dX (where a is scalar and X is matrix) --> matrix

dv/dX (where v is vector and X is matrix) --> ???

dY/dX (where Y is matrix and X is matrix) --> ???

By treating X as a systematically organized vector, you can simply use vector calculus theory and avoid the nuisance of figuring out how to organize the resulting derivative.

He did post the other version: da/dX --> matrix for trace operators:
[Here](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~nydic001/docs/unpubs/Schonemann_Trace_Derivatives_Presentation.pdf)