# Choosing the adequate layout convention for matrix derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Is there a rule (or maybe a rule of thumb) that provides guidance for choosing the layout convention (see [Layout conventions, wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions)) to use when dealing with matrix derivatives?

I found a hint in this answer  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/345946) to a related question but I could hardly find any well justified answer.

Comment: Try working a few problems in each. Then pick the one you like best and stick with it. And if you read an article using the other convention, it isn't difficult to translate it to your preferred convention.

Comment: @greg That's what I've been doing. But, I believe the layouts are not equivalently meaningful. Of course, any layout would give the derivatives but the arrangement seems important. This is explained in a section of Magnus and Neudecker's "Matrix Differential Calculus" (under First-order diﬀerentials and Jacobian matrices) that talks about why some notation (layout) is bad. The authors also give what they consider good notation and why.

Comment: Magnus and Neudecker make some good points. I would suggest that you read "Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives" by Are Hjorungnes for another point of view.

Comment: @greg Okay, thank you for the reference.